# UIImageView is it possible to reverses animation?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

i try to make an animation on UIImageView. is it enough ? or i need to use Core animation instead?

i want to animate

picture  1 , 2, 3, ..., 14

how to reanimate from 14, 13 ,12 ,..., 1

here is my code

```
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe01.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe02.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe03.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe04.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe05.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe06.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe07.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe08.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe09.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe10.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe11.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe12.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe13.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"phe14.png"],
                         nil];

    UIImageView *myAnimatedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 460-256,  320, 256)];
//  [myAnimatedView initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
    myAnimatedView.animationImages = myImages;
    //myAnimatedView.animationDuration = 0.75; // seconds
    myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 0; // 0 = loops forever
    //myAnimatedView.autoreverses=YES;
    [myAnimatedView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:myAnimatedView];
    [myAnimatedView release];
```

Comment: Are you looking for a slideshow type thing?

Answer (score 0):

See [How do you "ping pong" a UIView image sequence animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353085/how-do-you-ping-pong-a-uiview-image-sequence-animation/1353168#1353168), but note that many people have crashes and low memory issues related to using UIImageView.animationImages, you would be better off rethinking your basic approach so that only 1 image is held in memory at a time.